# Ember.computed.sort doesn't seem to work

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a template like so:

```
{{#each rate in package.ratesSorted}}
  {{rate.year}}
{{/each}}
```

I want the rates to be sorted by ascending year, so I have:

```
 var Package = DS.Model.extend({
  rates: DS.hasMany('rate'),
  ratesSorted: Ember.computed.sort('rates', (a, b) => {
    return a.get('year') > b.get('year');
  })
});

Package.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {id: 1, rates: [1, 3, 4]}
  ]
});
```

And my rate Model looks like this:

```
var Rate = DS.Model.extend({
  year: DS.attr('number'),
});

Rate.reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {id: 4, year: 4},
    {id: 1, year: 1},
    {id: 3, year: 3}
  ]
});
```

But it then ends up being sorted `3,4,1`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `Ember.computed.sorted` expects `-1` and `1` rather than true or false.

```
var Package = DS.Model.extend({
  ratesSorted: Ember.computed.sort('rates', (a, b) => a.get('year') < b.get('year') ? -1 : 1)
});
```

Works. Using sorting definitions, a better version is:

```
var Package = DS.Model.extend({
  rateSorting: ['year'],
  ratesSorted: Ember.computed.sort('rates', 'rateSorting')
});
```