# Ember sort newly added data

Tags: ember.js

I started working on a new ember project. I have never used ember before.

I am working with an api that does not conform with the JSON API spec and does not have a websocket.

So I poll the api to get the latest data.

I can get the latest data but it is rendered in the view on the bottom instead of the top. I have looked at [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280354/ember-computed-sort-doesnt-seem-to-work), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259400/how-to-observe-for-changes-in-the-ember-data-store), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318282/how-to-sort-model-using-only-a-route-in-ember) to no avail.

How do I get the new data to render at the top of the list?

```
//sample output after a new job fetched
2
1
3

//desired output
3
2
1
```

This is a new project so I don't want to use anything that will be depreciated in 2.0 (controllers, etc.). I am open to changing the model(s) if that works.

My route looks like this:

```
//routes query.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var interval = 1000; // every second
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      this.model().then(function(json) {
        this.controller.set('model', json);
      }.bind(this));
    }, interval);

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        query: this.store.find('query'),
        job: this.store.peekAll('job')
      });
  },
});
```

My models are:

```
//models query.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  jobs: DS.hasMany('job'),
  count: DS.attr('number'),
  jobQ: ['took'],
  jobsSorted: Ember.computed.sort('jobs', 'jobQ'), <-- this doesn't seem to work
});

//models job.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  submitter: DS.attr('string'),
  submission_time: DS.attr('date'), // '2015-04-27 15:14:55', // date?
  completion_time: DS.attr('date'), // '2015-04-27 15:15:08',
  took: DS.attr('number'),
  statuses: DS.attr('string'), // object
  query: DS.belongsTo('query'),
});
```

So my serializer is:

```
// serializers query.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import assign from 'npm:object-assign';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  isNewSerializerAPI: true,
  normalizeResponse: function (store, primaryModelClass, payload) {

    // delete things we don't want
    delete payload.error;
    delete payload.status;

    // populate array
    var jobs = [],
        relationships = [];

    // copies the jobs to a new var keep the payload clean
    Object.keys(payload.jobs).forEach((key) => {
      let attributes = {};
      assign(attributes, payload.jobs[key]);
      delete attributes.id;
      jobs.push({ id: key, type: 'job', attributes: attributes});
      relationships.push({ id: key, type: 'job'});
    });

    var c =  payload.count;

    //jobs
    // [{
    //  id:
    //  type:
    //  attributes: {
    //    name:
    //    filter:
    //    ...
    //  },
    //  ...
    // }]

    return {
      data: {
        id: 1,
        type: 'query',
        relationship: {
          job: {
            data: relationships
          }
        },
        attributes: { count: c }
      },
      included: jobs
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: I changed my model to not use the `hasMany` relationship. Instead of multiple models, I throw the array of jobs in an undefined attributed on the `query` model with `jobs: DS.attr()`. This seems to work but doesn't seem to be the preferred way. With that change I have access to all of the data in the model in the component which can be displayed. Then when the model is updated, the component also updates as desired.

Answer (score 0):

A template that looks like this would work just fine:

```
{{#each model.query as |query|}}
  {{#each query.jobsSorted as |job|}}
    {{job.took}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

What does your template look like? Although to sort it on a descending order you would need to add `:desc` to the sort order:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  jobs: DS.hasMany('job'),
  count: DS.attr('number'),
  jobQ: ['took:desc'],
  jobsSorted: Ember.computed.sort('jobs', 'jobQ')
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating that `Ember.computed.sort` works like you're trying to use it: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/towerukafa/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks Kit. My template is very sparse presently. I added both of your suggestions but neither worked. To get the jobs displayed currently, I have the following template: 

`{{#each model.job as |job|}}
  {{#query-job job=job}}
  {{/query-job}}
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}`

Comment: The new data remains appended to the bottom of the list. I may not have been clear in my explanation of the problem. I can get a dataset that returns  1 and 2. Then some time passes, another entity is added to the dataset on the server. Ember grabs the new data set which returns 2 and 3. 3 is then rendered below 1 and 2. 3 is added to the model. In the Ember console add-on I can see that it is added to the bottom of the model. So my display seems to reflect that of the data in the model. Maybe this could be solved by sorting the model? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @khornberg That's because your output is `model.jobs` instead of `model.jobsSorted`. My original block of code had a small issue in the inner loop (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31619889/revisions). Here's another example where I'm polling for new models and adding them: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rujomuvoso/2/edit?html,css,js,output Basically you need to do something like: `{{#each model.jobsSorted as |job|}} {{#query-job job=job}} {{/query-job}} {{/each}} {{outlet}}`.

Comment: `jobsSorted` is blank. Your examples on jsbin work. It doesn't work on my end. It may have to do with the fact that the job data is coming in as a compound document with the query data. So I'm only doing a `peekAll` into the store instead of a `findAll`.  I appreciate your help though.